# Reactive Extensions Unsubscribe issue

Tags: c#, system.reactive, subscribe, unsubscribe

I am trying to dynamically add and remove subscribers to an Observable BlockingCollection using the ThreadPoolScheduler.

I am not sure if this is a problem with my code or in RX itself, but I had assumed in this case I should be able to subscribe/unsubscribe as needed.

I have reduced the issue down to the test pasted below.

The code works correctly until I call Dispose on subscribers and then add new subscribers.
Essentially I seem to get old threads still de-queing the Observables but never doing anything with them.

Here is the unit test, it sets up 32 subscribers, adds 64 objects, then unsubscribes and repeats the same test. I have removed any additional code (and added some sleeps just for the test to make sure the threads are def done before I unsubscribe)

The first 64 are processed correctly, but the second set only 32 objects are passed to my subscriber.

```
[TestClass]
public class RxTests
{
    public class ObservTest
    {

        public BlockingCollection<ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable> mBlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable>();
        public IObservable<ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable> mObservableBlockingCollection;

        private static readonly object ObservableLock = new object();
        private static volatile ObservTest ObservableInstance;

        public static ObservTest Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (ObservableInstance != null)
                    return ObservableInstance;
                lock (ObservableLock)
                {
                    if (ObservableInstance == null)
                    {
                        ObservTest observable = new ObservTest();
                        observable.mObservableBlockingCollection = observable.mBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable().ToObservable(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
                        ObservableInstance = observable;
                    }
                    return ObservableInstance;
                }
            }
        }

        private int count = 0;
        public void Release()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            Console.WriteLine("Release {0} : {1}", count, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        public void LogCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total :{0}", count);
        }

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        IList<IDisposable> subscribers = new List<IDisposable>();

        for (int count = 0; count < 32; count++)
        {
            IDisposable disposable = ObservTest.Instance.mObservableBlockingCollection.Subscribe(Observe);
            subscribers.Add(disposable);
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < 64; count++)
        {
            ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable observable = new ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable
            {
                Name = string.Format("{0}", count)
            };
            ObservTest.Instance.mBlockingCollection.Add(observable);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        foreach (IDisposable disposable in subscribers)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        subscribers.Clear();

        for (int count = 0; count < 32; count++)
        {
            IDisposable disposable = ObservTest.Instance.mObservableBlockingCollection.Subscribe(Observe);
            subscribers.Add(disposable);
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < 64; count++)
        {
            ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable observable = new ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable
            {
                Name = string.Format("{0}", count)
            };
            ObservTest.Instance.mBlockingCollection.Add(observable);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        ObservTest.Instance.LogCount();

    }

    public static void Observe(ObserverTests.UnitTestObservable observable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Observe {0} : {1}", observable.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        ObservTest.Instance.Release();
    }
}
```

So the final count in the output is 96 when I would expect it to be 128

If I reduce the number of initial subscribers from 32 the processed count increases.
e.g. if I reduce the count from 32 to 16 in the first loop I get a count of 112.
if I reduce it to 8 I get 120

I am aiming for a system where as the number of tasks being executed is increased so too are the number of subscribers available to process them.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?